# How many gloss coats on a primed and undercoated external door?

Tags: wood, paint, exterior

I stripped a wooden exterior door back to bare wood.

It was then primed and soft-sanded.

Then I applied two coats of undercoat. It's a grey colour.

Since then, I've applied 5 coats of exterior Gloss - from a paint manufacturer used/recommended by tradespeople.

The exterior gloss is a fuchsia-pink, but the grey undercoat is still showing in the strokes. It is coming up more pink with each coat but I'm concerned about putting on too many coats.

Any advice?

Comment: 5 coats of gloss? either you have thinned it too much or not applying a good coat. Used to gloss machinery and a single gloss coat was fine - just don't get any runs.

Comment: Generally, you put on as many coats as necessary to get the finish color/quality you're after. Also, you usually want to use a _white_ primer under a light color, as it will make the finish coat brighter. Add too many coats and your door might get to be too big to close completely. You might be getting to the point of needing to strip it back to bare wood, apply a single coat of white primer, then your color top coat (or two). You may want to go back to the people who recommended this combination to ask them (for advice and a contribution to more paint!).

Comment: Why did you do two coats of grey undercoat? Was the primer, presumably white, insufficient?